# Catching throwables vs exceptions before calling CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Throwable)

Tags: java, future, executorservice, completable-future, throwable

I know the web is full of advice not to catch `Throwable`s, but does it apply when working with `CompleteableFuture`s? For example, in

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    es.submit(() -> {
        try {
            cf.complete(getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) { // should I catch Throwable instead?
            cf.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });
```

Should I catch `Throwable` or `Exception`? If I catch `Exception` and `Error` is thrown, program will most likely go into deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that not catching `Throwable` bears the risk of the `CompletableFuture` never getting completed. So this risk will justify catching `Error`s resp. all `Throwable`s which you normally wouldn’t.

But since you are basically reinventing `supplyAsync`, let’s compare the behavior of the two:

```
public class CF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        CompletableFuture<String> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getValue(), es);
        try {
            cf1.join();
        }
        catch(CompletionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.err.println();

        CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = new CompletableFuture<>();
        es.submit(() -> {
            try {
                cf2.complete(getValue());
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                cf2.completeExceptionally(t);
            }
        });

        try {
            cf2.join();
        }
        catch(CompletionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getValue() {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    }
}
```

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at CF.getValue(CF.java:39)
    at CF.lambda$main$0(CF.java:11)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 3 more

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:412)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2044)
    at CF.main(CF.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at CF.getValue(CF.java:39)
    at CF.lambda$main$1(CF.java:24)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

So we see, catching errors is the standard behavior of `CompletableFuture`. Only the stack traces differ. Let’s see whether we can raise the convergence:

```
public class CF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        CompletableFuture<String> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getValue(), es);
        try {
            cf1.join();
        }
        catch(CompletionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.err.println();

        CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = new CompletableFuture<>();
        es.submit(() -> {
            try {
                cf2.complete(getValue());
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                cf2.completeExceptionally(new CompletionException(t));
            }
        });

        try {
            cf2.join();
        }
        catch(CompletionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getValue() {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    }
}
```

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at CF.getValue(CF.java:39)
    at CF.lambda$main$0(CF.java:11)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 3 more

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at CF.lambda$main$1(CF.java:26)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at CF.getValue(CF.java:39)
    at CF.lambda$main$1(CF.java:24)
    ... 5 more
```

That’s quiet close.

Of course, if `getValue()` doesn’t throw checked exceptions, there is no reason not to use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getValue(), es);`. If we have a reason to implement the completion manually, like having to handle checked exceptions, there are some things we can improve. If we don’t need the `Future` returned by `submit`, we can use `execute` instead, to avoid the creation of an unneeded `FutureTask`. Further, `CompletableFuture` marks its completion tasks with [`AsynchronousCompletionTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask.html) to help monitoring and debugging and its useful to follow the convention:

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = new CompletableFuture<>();
es.execute((Runnable & CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask)() -> {
    try {
        cf2.complete(getValue());
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        cf2.completeExceptionally(new CompletionException(t));
    }
});
```

There is no direct consequence for the actual behavior though.